# D3 Zooming Arrowheads

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am working on a directed acyclic graph using the force layout in D3. I had markers working with the code:

```
graph.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["end"])
    .enter().append("svg:marker")    
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
. . .
var link = graph.append("svg:g").selectAll("line")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("svg:line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

However, once I added the zooming feature the arrowheads no longer show up on the edges. My initial impression of the issue is that I have changed the nesting of appends such that the link and definition is now appended onto a *g* element instead of directly onto an *svg* element.

The entire snippet of relevant code is below:

```
var graphDiv = d3.select("#graph");
var graphBase = graphDiv.append("svg:svg");
. . .
var graph = graphBase.call(zoom.on("zoom", redraw))
    .append("svg:g");
. . .
graph.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["end"])
    .enter().append("svg:marker")    
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
. . .
var link = graph.append("svg:g").selectAll("line")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("svg:line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

With this code, the arrowheads to not appear on the graph at all. When I change the following lines:

```
graphBase.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
var link = graphBase.append("svg:g").selectAll("line")
```

the arrowheads reappear but when trying to zoom or pan the graph, the edges and arrowheads do not move at all. This makes sense because now the edges are no longer a part of the zoom behavior, however I am not sure what I need to change to make the arrowheads appear in the zooming graph.

I have spent a while looking for other possible sources, but have not found anything that is quite as complex or with as many features as my current project. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.